# Prove that $ f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function  such that $f(i)=0\ \forall i\in \Bbb Z$ .Then is it true  that $ f$ is uniformly continuous ?

let $\epsilon >0$ be given.Then I have to find a $\delta 
>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $ whenever  $
|x-y|<\delta $. Since $f$ is continuous at all points then corresponding to $\epsilon >0 \exists \delta_a >0 $ 
such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $ whenever  $
|x-a|<\delta_a \forall a\in \Bbb R$.I have to prove that $\delta =\inf\{\delta_a >0;a\in \Bbb R\}>0$ exists

How should I do that?

Comment: Are you sure this function is uniformly continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance consider $f$ such that $f(i)=0 \; \forall i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and for each integer $n\ge 0$, $f(n+1/2)=n$ and $f$ is linear in $[n,n+1/2], [n+1/2, n+1]$

Then for continuity at midpoints of consecutive integers required $\delta$ for a given $\varepsilon$ gets smaller and smaller so no fixed $\delta$ can work for all such points.

Comment: Very impressed by the answer+1

Comment: @Amartya Thanks :) Edited a lot of unwanted errors

Comment: What do you mean by n is it natural number or integer? @user160738

Comment: @PranitaGupta An integer $n\ge 0$ can be interpreted as natural numbers if you include $0$ as one of them; I think I just wanted to dis-ambiguate (is that an English word? hope you understand what I mean) instead of saying let $n$ be a natural number. It doesn't really matter whether we include $0$ or not. The point was that $f$ has 'spikes' of height $n$ on the intervals $[n,n+1]$ which achive its height at the midpoint and is linear otherwise with each integer points being $0$.

Answer (score 8):

Take $\sin (\pi x^2)$, this is not uniform continuous.