# Continuous real valued function that is zero on integers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous  function such that $f(i)=0 \;\; \forall i\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Which of the following statements is always true?

A) The image of $f$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$

B) The image of $f$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

C) $f$ is uniformly continuous

D) none of above

Since we can take $f$ to be zero function, option B is wrong. What about the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $f(x)=h(x)$Sin$(\pi x)$ satisfies $f(i)= 0$  $ \forall i \in \bf Z$,Now can you find suitable $h$ to contadict options $a$ and $c$ ?

Comment: taking h(x)=x,gives me nonuniform continuous  function

Comment: but what about other one??

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574837/prove-that-f-is-uniformly-continuous?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in Z$ : For $x\in [n,n+1/2]$ let $f(x)=-(1-2^{-|n|})(x-n)(n+1/2-x).$ For $x\in [n+1/2,n+1]$ let $f(x)=|\sin (4\pi n(x-n-1/2))|$. The image of $f$ is $ (-1/4,1]$ which is neither open nor closed. And $f$ is not uniformly continuous because $f'(n+3/4)=4\pi |n| $, and $\{4\pi |n| :n\in Z\}$ is an unbounded set.